# Pip doesnt recognise public pypi after codeartifact used once

Tags: python, pip, pypi, aws-codeartifact

- After I used Codeartifact for installing a package once,
  pip stopped trying public Pypi and prompts for my codeartifact credentials every time.
- I have checked the .pypirc and it does not contain anything regarding CodeArtifact
- Can somebody please **suggest** what could be the problem **or direct** me on the right way to investigate it myself?

I am not a great specialist of pip and usually install
my packages only through the IDE plugins (which seem to work just fine),
But this is problematic when running scripts that contain pip install's.

Thanks in Advance!

-- EDIT : I edited pip.conf as well to specifically point to the public pypi.  Didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

What was the edit on the pip.conf  I had the same issue and by changing the pip.conf from awsartifact to :

`trusted-host = pypi.python.org pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org`

It worked

Comment: Can you please specify which `pip.conf` you are referring to?  I assume `~/.pip/pip.conf` but would like to be sure. Thank you. https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#config-file